# pathlib Path and py.test LocalPath

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pathlib

I have started using `pathlib.Path` some time ago and I like using it. Now that I have gotten used to it, I have gotten sloppy and forget to cast arguments to `str`.

This often happens when using `tox` + `py.test` with temporary directories based on `tmpdir` (which is a `py._path.local.LocalPath`):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pytest

def test_tmpdir(tmpdir):
    p = Path(tmpdir) / 'testfile.csv'
```

Instead of inserting `str()` every time, I looked at solving this more generally, but could not.

First I tried to make my own Path class that has an adapted `_parse_args`:

```
import pytest
from py._path.local import LocalPath
from pathlib import Path, PurePath

def Path(Path):
    @classmethod
    def _parse_args(cls, args):
        parts = []
        for a in args:
            if isinstance(a, PurePath):
                parts += a._parts
            elif isinstance(a, str):
                # Force-cast str subclasses to str (issue #21127)
                parts.append(str(a))
            elif isinstance(a, LocalPath):
                parts.append(str(a))
            else:
                raise TypeError(
                    "argument should be a path or str object, not %r"
                    % type(a))
        return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)

def test_subclass(tmpdir):
    p = Path(tmpdir) / 'testfile.csv'
```

This throws a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'str'` (tried with `PosixPath` as well, same result, would prefer not to be Linux specific).

The I tried to monkey-patch `Path`:

```
import pytest
from pathlib import Path

def add_tmpdir():
    from py._path.local import LocalPath

    org_attr = '_parse_args'
    stow_attr = '_org_parse_args'

    def parse_args_localpath(cls, args):
        args = list(args)
        for idx, a in enumerate(args):
            if isinstance(a, LocalPath):
                args[idx] = str(a)
        return getattr(cls, stow_attr)(args)

    if hasattr(Path, stow_attr):
        return  # already done
    setattr(Path, stow_attr, getattr(Path, org_attr))
    setattr(Path, org_attr, parse_args_localpath)

add_tmpdir()

def test_monkeypatch_path(tmpdir):
    p = Path(tmpdir) / 'testfile.csv'
```

This throws a `AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute '_flavour'` (also when monkey-patching PurePath).

And finally I tried just wrapping `Path`:

```
import pytest
import pathlib

def Path(*args):
    from py._path.local import LocalPath
    args = list(args)
    for idx, a in enumerate(args):
        if isinstance(a, LocalPath):
            args[idx] = str(a)
    return pathlib.Path(*args)

def test_tmpdir_path(tmpdir):
    p = Path(tmpdir) / 'testfile.csv'
```

Which also gives the `AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute '_flavour'`

I thought at some point this last one worked, but I cannot reproduce that. 

Am I doing something wrong? Why is this so hard?

Comment: FWIW pytest plans to switch to pathlib some day: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That last one (wrapping) should work, I suspect you actually test all of these in one `py.test`/`tox` run and that monkey-patch is still in effect (that might explain why it worked at some point, the order of the test files etc matters if you start to change things on global classes).

That this is hard, is because of `Path` essentially being a generator, that on the fly decides whether you are on Windows or Linux, and creates a `WindowsPath` resp. `PosixPath` accordingly.

BDFL Guido van Rossum already [indicated](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/1196986#1196986) in May 2015:

> It does sound like subclassing Path should be made easier.

but nothing happened. Support for `pathlib` in 3.6 within other standard libraries has increased, but pathlib itself still has the same problems.

Comment: When tested on its own this wrapping works! What is a pity is that it works for the first argument only, where I hoped that changing _parse_args could also help when adding segments is there no chance to get that to work?

Comment: @Alois That is more complex than just wrapping, but can be done. You better post it as a (separate) follow-up question. In any case you would not want to have ` / tmpdir /` as `tmpdir` is an absolute path (`str(tmpdir)` starts with `/`)

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else is researching whether pytest's `tmpdir` paths play nicely with `pathlib.Path`:

Using `python 3.6.5` and `pytest 3.2.1`, the code posted in the question works perfectly fine without explicitly casting to `str`:

```
from pathlib import Path

def test_tmpdir(tmpdir):
    p = Path(tmpdir) / 'testfile.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, you can create a fixture to do the wrapping automatically:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def tmppath(tmpdir):
    return Path(tmpdir)
```

Then you can just use `tmppath` instead of `tmpdir` in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `tmp_path` which is a `pathlib.Path` object ([source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html)).