# pathlib.path allowing other types for joining apart from string and Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

How can I change `pathlib.Path._parse_args`, so that I cannot only have other types (like  `LocalPath`) as arguments to `Path` but also use other types as parameter for `/` based joining, etc..?

```
from pathlib import Path
Path(tmplib) / 25 / True
```

With `tmplib` a `LocalPath` from `py._path.local`, and the others automatically converted to their `str()` representations?

I tried sub-classing and monkey-patching as shown in this ([pathlib Path and py.test LocalPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40784950/7204727)) question but that did not work.

`Path` looks very resistant to extending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathlib` (and `pathlib2` for Python versions < 3.4) primarily consists of four  classes directly related to paths  `Path`, `PosixPath`, `WindowsPath` and `PurePath` (`BasePath` in `pathlib2`). If you subclass each of these and copy and adapt the code for `Path.__new__()` and `PurePath._parse_args()` in the following way:

```
import os
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 4):
    import pathlib2 as pathlib
else:
    import pathlib


class PurePath(pathlib.Path):
    __slots__ = ()
    types_to_stringify = [int]

    @classmethod
    def _parse_args(cls, args):
        # This is useful when you don't want to create an instance, just
        # canonicalize some constructor arguments.
        parts = []
        for a in args:
            if isinstance(a, pathlib.PurePath):
                parts += a._parts
            elif sys.version_info < (3,) and isinstance(a, basestring):
                # Force-cast str subclasses to str (issue #21127)
                parts.append(str(a))
            elif sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(a, str):
                # Force-cast str subclasses to str (issue #21127)
                parts.append(str(a))
            elif isinstance(a, tuple(PurePath.types_to_stringify)):
                parts.append(str(a))
            else:
                try:
                    parts.append(a)
                except:
                    raise TypeError(
                        "argument should be a path or str object, not %r"
                        % type(a))
        return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)


class WindowsPath(PurePath, pathlib.PureWindowsPath):
    __slots__ = ()


class PosixPath(PurePath, pathlib.PurePosixPath):
    __slots__ = ()


class Path(pathlib.Path):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Path:
            cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
        self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
        if not self._flavour.is_supported:
            raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
                                      % (cls.__name__,))
        self._init()
        return self
```

you will have a `Path` that already understand `int` and can be used to do:

```
from py._path.local import LocalPath

# extend the types to be converted to string on the fly
PurePath.types_to_stringify.extend([LocalPath, bool])

tmpdir = LocalPath('/var/tmp/abc')

p = Path(tmpdir) / 14 / False / 'testfile.yaml'
print(p)
```

to get:

```
/var/tmp/abc/14/False/testfile.yaml
```

(you'll need to install package `pathlib2` for versions < 3.4 for this to work on those).

The above `Path` can be used as `open(p)` in Python 3.6.

Adapting `_parse_args` gives you automatic support for `/` (`__truediv__`) as well as methods like `joinpath()`, `relative_to()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to keep the platform independence magic:

```
from py._path.local import LocalPath
import os
import pathlib


class Path(pathlib.Path):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Path:
            cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
        return cls._from_parts(map(str, args))

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return super().__truediv__(str(other))

class WindowsPath(Path, pathlib.WindowsPath):
    pass
class PosixPath(Path, pathlib.PosixPath):
    pass

p = Path(LocalPath())
print(p / 25 / True)
```

Or just this if it's ok to be platform specific:

```
from py._path.local import LocalPath
import pathlib


class Path(pathlib.PosixPath):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls._from_parts(map(str, args))

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return super().__truediv__(str(other))


p = Path(LocalPath())
print(p / 25 / True)
```

Comment: Although it looks simpler than my solution, this will not complain about **any** type that can be represented as a string. And if you want to use  `joinpath()`, `realtive_to()`, etc., you have to bring in each of those definitions as well.